# How can I measure the minimum distance between a pointGraphicOverlay to a tortuous lineGraphicOverlay in ArcGIS for Android?

Tags: java, android, arcgis

I want to measure the minimum distance between a point Graphic overlay to a tortuous line Graphic overlay which get from a set of points.I know how to measure distance between point to point ,but I did not find the API to solve my problem.

Comment: Can you post any code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate across the points in the tortuous line, calculating the distance of each from your fixed point, use the shortest?

This will not always give the minimum distance - it is possible that a line between two points will approach the fixed point more closely than the points at the end of the line.

If you want to take that into account then you will need to find the minimum distance between the fixed point and every line segment p[n], p[n+1].  This will take more time and involves some fun math.....

Comment: thanks for your help ,I just used the shortest distance to the set of points at present